# resize root partition without using live cd and lvm

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do partitions needed to be unmounted when resizing a partition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/450085/do-partitions-needed-to-be-unmounted-when-resizing-a-partition)

I want to know if it is possible to resize an existing root partition without using live cd.
The server is running on centos and I prefer not to use lvm and mounting of partitions. 
Just resizing the existing partition.
Below are the partitions:

```
[root@61540 ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14        1058     8393962+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3            1059        7457    51399967+  83  Linux

[root@61540 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3              48G   12G   34G  26% /
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Edit: Below are the filesystems

```
[root@61540 ~]# mount
/dev/sda3 on / type ext3 (rw,usrquota,grpquota)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
```

In my case I want to add the unallocated space of my 2TB disk to sda3 partition.
Are there any way to resize the partition aside from using a live cd? because I have no direct access to the server.
I also encounter parted but I can't unmount the partition because some OS files is stored there.
What are my other options?

Edit: [I just recently came upon this article](http://raftaman.net/?p=228), and I want to confirm if deleting a partition using fdisk will not delete the data on the partition.

[I also came upon this article](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions) that states it is must to have live cd or rescue system to resize the root partition.

Is it safe for me to follow the instructions from the [first article](http://raftaman.net/?p=228) that I refer?

Comment: What type of file system are you using on the root partition?

Comment: its ext3. i added it on question description also. thanks @EEAA

Comment: If you want to experiment, I **strongly** recommend you build a virtual machine with a basic setup, and similar partitioning to your existing disk.  Do not try it on production, until you have the procedure down perfectly in a VM.  Also, **make a BACKUP**.

Comment: Are you also the Jan Mark who is the author of this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/450085/do-partitions-needed-to-be-unmounted-when-resizing-a-partition/ ?

Comment: -@MadHatter I read about an [online positive resizing article here](http://raftaman.net/?p=228). Is this is an example of the online resizing you mention in the other question?. Resizing without any live cd.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way you can make profit from your 2 TB is not by extending the root partition but by creating other partitions and mounting them under /home, /var, /opt or whatever mount point depending on what you are going use that space for.

Here is a guide about linux partitioning for further information : http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/disk-partitioning.html